# 'http-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, angular-seed

After installing angular-seed project, i did the following steps:

Cloned the repository :

> git clone https://github.com/angular/angular-seed.git
>
> cd angular-seed

Then I ran npm install

at the end of the install i get:

> > angular-seed@0.0.0 prestart C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\comilion\angular-seed
> >     npm install
> >
> > angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\myproject\angular-seed
> >     bower install
> >
> > angular-seed@0.0.0 start C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\myproject\angular-seed
> >     http-server -a localhost -p 2324
>
> 'http-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 start: `http-server -a localhost -p 2324`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   angular-seed@0.0.0 start script. npm ERR! This is most likely a
>   problem with the angular-seed package, npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!
>   http-server -a localhost -p 2324 npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-seed npm ERR! There is likely
>   additional logging output above. npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   npm ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start" npm ERR!
>   cwd C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\myproject\angular-seed npm ERR!
>   node -v v0.10.22 npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.14 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm
>   ERR! npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\myproject\angular-seed\npm-debug.log

please let me know if you have any suggestions how to solve this issue.

Comment: `http-server` needs to be installed globally with `npm install -g http-server`.

Comment: thanks @BenFortune it worked please write it as an answer so i can make it as correct.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

@BenFortune found the answer it was

http-server needs to be installed globally with `npm install -g http-server`

Comment: This solves the issue but it does not have to be installed globally. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31340713/5598783

Answer (score 26):

If the accepted solution did not work for you. Try the following. This solved the issue in my system.

Make sure the locations of both npm and http-server are added in environment variable 'PATH' (Both user variable and System variable).

If it is not present,

add `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm` and `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\http-server` to environment variable 'PATH'

Comment: Was looking for exact path and here it is. Thanks :)

Comment: I had to open command tool in Administrator mode to get http-server working.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Window 10. Then after run

```
npm install -g http-server
```

The `http-server.cmd` will available in `C:\Users\your-user\AppData\Roaming\npm`

[image]
  
Then check if `http-server` work in `cmd` or not.

- If it works, you don't need to see the below part.
- If it not work. You need to check `Environment Variable`

[image]

- If you add variable to `Path` (inside admin). You need to run `cmd` as Administrator.
- If you add variable to `Path` (inside System variable). You don't need to run `cmd` as Administrator.

[image]

- Add `C:\Users\your-user\AppData\Roaming\npm` -> `OK` -> `OK` -> `Re-open the cmd`.
- The `http-server` will work

Answer (score 4):

```
npm install -g http-server
```

Use this command to install `http-server` module into your project. You can verify this in `package.json`

Answer (score 3):

You can fix the issues by doing the following steps,

1. Install http-server globally by `npm install -g http-server`
2. Added 'PATH' in environment variable for system variable. Path will be like this `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Comment: Hi, I am getting the error http-server : The term 'http-server' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet when I run http-server. It was working fine till yesterday and all of sudden its trowing this error. I verified the Path for both npm and http-server in Environmental variables and added them, but still issue not fixed. I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling the http-server. Any idea what might be the issue.

Comment: I found the solution for my issue and just sharing it here so if someone needs it. In the Path as mentioned above when I specify `%AppData%\Roaming\npm\node_modules`, the error is displayed. The reason is because the %AppData% was already set as `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming` in my profile and so the folder path I gave is invalid. When I removed that Roaming from the path then it started working.

Answer (score 0):

For me all that had to be done after the basic install

```
npm install http-server -g
```

Is to **run as administrator** from the project directory this command:

```
http-server dist/project-name
```

Answer (score 0):

1-remove http-server by command

```
npm uninstall http-server -g
```

2- install again

```
npm install http-server -g
```