# node 'http-server' only works as administrator from powershell

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm

Having installed the 'http-server' module using npm, I can only run it if I start powershell as admin.

eg:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

Seems to work fine, but then:

```
http-server
```

Throws the error:

```
http-server : The term 'http-server' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

However if I start powershell as an administrator, 'http-server' starts the server as expected.

How can I install the npm/node http-server to be available when powershell is not run as administrator?

Duplicate police: This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245230/http-server-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command), but the problem is different (my install was global from the get go) and the solution there doesn't work for me unless run as admin.

Comment: Does `http-server` use port 80? Doesn't using port 80 require admin privs?

Comment: By default it uses 8080, is that covered by the same restrictions?

Comment: Is `$ENV:Path` different when running as admin vs normal user?

Comment: arco44 is probably on the right path - this error simply means that it can't associate that string with a command or function... looking at port number is going too far.

Comment: @AndrewM I believe not. Only 1024 ports and below requires admin priv.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your PATH environment variable includes the path to your http-server. You can do this in the user's powershell profile. You can find a basic introductory to powershell profiles [here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ee692764.aspx)

Comment: I've added this into environment variable but still facing same issue. can you help me