# How to start http-server locally

Tags: npm, httpserver

I cloned [angular seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) which is using node `http-server` and it is working perfectly using following configuration.

> Command : npm start (from root of project)

Following configuration in `package.json` file:

```
"start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1",
Link to file
```

However I'm unable to start this server directly. eg: from root of the project, none of these commands work:

```
>  angular-seed npm http-server  
>  angular-seed node http-server
>  angular-seed http-server
```

Shouldn't this(http-server) be available here(root, where it got installed from)? Could someone please explain me how it is working and how I can use it directly from root of the project.

I'm sure it will work fine if I install it globally but I'm not interested in that.

Comment: npm install http-server, and in package.json, add: **"scripts": {"start": "http-server"}**, then run: npm start, browse: http://127.0.0.1:8080

Answer (score 73, accepted):

When you're running `npm install` in the project's root, it installs all of the npm dependencies into the project's `node_modules` directory.

If you take a look at the project's `node_modules` directory, you should see a directory called `http-server`, which holds the `http-server` package, and a `.bin` folder, which holds the executable binaries from the installed dependencies. The `.bin` directory should have the `http-server` binary (or a link to it).

So in your case, you should be able to start the `http-server` by running the following from your project's root directory (instead of `npm start`):

```
./node_modules/.bin/http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1
```

This should have the same effect as running `npm start`.

If you're running a Bash shell, you can simplify this by adding the `./node_modules/.bin` folder to your `$PATH` environment variable:

```
export PATH=./node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

This will put this folder on your path, and you should be able to simply run

```
http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1
```

Comment: This works for me, but only when using `\\` instead of '/'. Thanks

Comment: Could you please update it for those who use Windows command? There is no export. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, can't do that - I don't use Windows. I'm sure that you can find a way to set the PATH variable in Windows, though. Please feel free to update the answer with Windows instructions when you have found out how to do this.

Comment: Windows "Command Shell (cmd)" can use `SET PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;%PATH%` and Windows/macOS/Linux "Powershell (pwsh)" can use `$env:PATH=$("./node_modules/.bin" + [System.IO.Path]::SeparatorChar + "$env:PATH")` HTH! (PS. worth noting that pwsh is the preferred shell on Windows platform, today.)

Answer (score 16):

To start server locally paste the below code in **package.json** and run ***npm start*** 
in command line.

`"scripts": {
    "start": "http-server -c-1 -p 8081"
  },`