# Error when trying to run npm http-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, npm, server

I have a node.js/angular2 project which I had previously been serving using lite-server but as I need to serve server-side files, I am switching to using http-server. To run lite server and the typescript compiler simultaneously before, I had the command: `"start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",` in my package.json. I initially switched it to `"start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"http-server\" ",` which I found gave the error:

```
[1] 'http-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
1] operable program or batch file.
1] http-server exited with code 1
```

After having seen [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328365/how-to-start-http-server-locally), I tried: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "./node_modules/http-server/bin"` which returned the same error.
**What is the correct command to run `http-server`?**

### UPDATE:

I modified my `package.json` as was suggested:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"node app/index.js\" ",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "http": "http-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "server": "http-server",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "cheerio": "latest",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "express": "latest",
    "file-system": "^2.2.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "request": "latest",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "latest",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

I ran the command `npm install http-server --save` in the project root and got the following errors:

```
+-- @reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.10  extraneous
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY reflect-metadata@0.1.3
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.15 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@0.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.15 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2 but none was installed.
```

**These packages were installed initially so what could be causing these errors?**

Comment: Those are not errors from `http-server`, which has no peer dependencies, but rather from rxjs from the looks of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corrent command is `http-server`, but you need to make sure you have http-server installed properly.

If you used `npm install -g http-server`, you just use `http-server`, anywhere. CLI or package.json scripts, doesn't matter, it just works.

If you used `npm install http-server --save` or save-dev etc, then you *still* just use `http-server`, but as part of a package.json script. It will then only work through npm scripts, because npm does all the environment bootstrapping for you. Don't try to guess at the http-server `bin` location.

For bonus points, capture all the different things as their own npm tasks, and then use npm task composition or something like `npm-run-all`:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "server": "http-server",
  "tsc": "tsc",
  "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
  "start": "npm-run-all tsc tsc:w server"
},
...
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "http-server": "...",
  ...
}
```

**2017 Edit**

Alternatively, if you don't want global packages, you can also use [npx](https://github.com/zkat/npx), as "the only thing you ever install globally" and then you can run local modules using `npx modulename`, in this case, `npx http-server`.

Comment: I initially installed http-server globally which seemed to work. When I did `npm install http-server --save` for some reason I'm getting a few errors. I'll update the post with what I did. Thanks

Comment: It seems that there was something wrong with the old project so I started a new one and installed the http-server again. It seems to be working now.

Comment: ah, yeah it's super annoying when that happens!